# Rails security: Avoiding mass-assignment altogether

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, activerecord

I tend to not need the [mass-assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) feature in my production code.  (In my test code, I use it a lot, but in those cases I *do* want to set arbitrary columns.)

So if, in my production code, I simply avoid these forms:

```
Article.new(params[:article])  # or create
article.attributes = params[:article]
article.update_attributes(params[:article])
```

and instead always manually enumerate all the attributes, like so:

```
Article.new(:title => params[:article][:title], :body => params[:article][:body], ...)
```

am I save from mass assignment security issues (even without using `attr_accessible`/`attr_protected`)?

**Edit:** The reason I'm not just disabling mass assignment is, I'd like to be able to write `Article.create!(:blog_id => @blog.id, ...)`, where blog_id is an "unsave" attribute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, using the 2nd method, you're safe from users assigning to other attributes.

This is a DRYer way to write it, though:

```
Article.new(params[:article].slice(:title, :body))
```

-or-

```
def article_params
  params[:article].slice(:title, :body)
end

Article.new(article_params)  # or create
article.attributes = article_params
article.update_attributes(article_params)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end of `config/environments/production.rb` :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:attr_accessible, nil)
```

Comment: But I don't want to do this, because I'd like to be able to write `User.create!(:name => 'J. R. Hacker', :admin => true)` in my test code.  My question is, if I don't globally disable mass assignment, am I still save?

Comment: The above will only apply to your production code, not your test code

Comment: Ah, right, of course.  Here's the problem though: If I do this, I have to write `a = Article.new; a.blog_id = blog.id; ...; a.save!`.  I'd much rather like to write `Article.create!(blog_id => blog.id, ...)` -- but I can only do that if I leave mass assignment open, even on unsafe attributes like blog_id.  So I'm wondering if that's a save thing to do at all (so long as I avoid passing in tainted hashes).

Comment: You are right, you will need to assign to each attribute in this case. You could use `attr_protected`, all attributes will be mass-assignable except those marked as protected.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get John Douthat's method working for multiple parameters, so I came up with the following alternative (taken from my CommentsController):

```
def set_params
  @comment.parent_id = params[:blog_comment][:parent_id] 
  @comment.ip_address = request.remote_ip
  @comment.commentator = current_user.username || "anonymous"
  @comment.name = params[:blog_comment][:name]
  @comment.email = params[:blog_comment][:email]
  @comment.url = params[:blog_comment][:url]
end

def create
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:blog_comment])
  set_params

  if @comment.save
  ...
end

def update
  @comment = Blog::Comment.find(params[:id])
  set_params

  if @comment.update_attributes(params[:blog_comment])
  ...
end
```