# Is there an opposite function of slice function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424430/rails-security-avoiding-mass-assignment-altogether), slice function is used to get only necessary elements of params. What would be the function I should use to exclude an element of params (such as user_id)?

```
Article.new(params[:article].slice(:title, :body))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use [except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except):

```
a = {"foo" => 0, "bar" => 42, "baz" => 1024 }
a.except("foo")
# returns => {"bar" => 42, "baz" => 1024}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `except` is a method that is added by Rails and is not normally available if working with Ruby by itself

Comment: Ruby 3 has added `except` to Hash. See docs [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-except)

Comment: also observe that, in Rails, the mutating version of the method, `except!`  returns the same as `except`, while it must probably rather return the excluded part (just to be aligned with its counterpart method, `slice!`. Maybe something to raise up with the Rails team.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired in the sourcecode of [except in Rails' ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/854587c268a5474f824215c84409d44466fba9dd/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb)

You can do the same without requiring `active_support/core_ext/hash/except`

```rb
# h.slice( * h.keys - [k1, k2...] )

# Example:
h = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
h.slice( * h.keys - [:b, :c] ) # => { a: 1, d: 4}
```

Note: Ruby 3+ Hash incorporated this `except` method:

```rb
# Ruby 3+
h.except(:b, :c) # => { a: 1, d: 4}
```

Comment: I knew there should be some nifty trick, although using Ruby 3+ doesn't require it.

Comment: @akostadinov, thanks for the tip. I'll add a note about Ruby 3+.

Answer (score 2):

Considering only standard Ruby.

For Ruby versions below 3, no.

For Ruby 3, yes. You can use [`except`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-except).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
params = { :title => "title", :other => "other", :body => "body"  }

params.select {|k,v| [:title, :body].include? k  } #=> {:title => "title", :body => "body"}
```

Comment: at least it's Ruby. To be fair, slice and except are both Rails methods.

Comment: Slice is Ruby, for the rest you are right.